# Python/CMD Как получить имя процесса на переднем плане

Tags: python, cmd

Например, у меня на переднем плане pycharm, и мне нужно, чтобы скрипт при активации написал в консоль имя процесса pycharm (pycharm64.exe)

Мне нужна либо функция в python, либо команда CMD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

если речь о windows, то потребуется используя модуль `ctypes`, немного повозиться с winapi:

1: получить список хэндлов окон

```
HWND GetTopWindow(
  [in, optional] HWND hWnd
);
```

и

```
void GetNextWindow(
  [in]  hWnd,
  [in]  wCmd
);
```

2: используя их получить хэндл процесса:

```
HANDLE WINAPI GetProcessHandleFromHwnd(
  _In_ HWND hwnd
);
```

3: имея хэндл процесса получить имя исполняемого файла

```
DWORD GetModuleFileNameExA(
  [in]           HANDLE  hProcess,
  [in, optional] HMODULE hModule,
  [out]          LPSTR   lpFilename,
  [in]           DWORD   nSize
);
```